# Does PHP support "Application Sessions"?

Tags: php

I've got a PHP app that stores arbitrary config info in a file. I would like to read that file once, when the app first starts, save it as some kind of application state variable, and leverage it across potentially thousands of user sessions. My Google foo is usually pretty good but in this case the only thing I'm able to come up with is the `$_SESSION` variable. Using it means reading the config file once *per user session*, which could mean reading it thousands of times a minute in high-volume installations, which seems inefficient.

When I worked with .NET web apps there was an idea of an [application session](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms952597.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) that could be used to persist app configuration information across multiple user sessions. Does PHP have a similar concept?

Comment: Caching. Something like memcached, redis, APC, etc. Use a key/value store. Pull from cache, if not in cache, set in cache. Other terms.... 'warm cache' and 'cold cache'.

Comment: So, we can install php extensions that support a global cache, but PHP doesn't have anything built-in?

Comment: File caches are typically slower than memory. All depends on your needs. Think of the cache layer in the abstract. You don't want to be locked into what it comes with - more a factor when starting to look at scaling out. PHP does typically provider APC(u) that you could use.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone `sqlite::memory` goes away at the end of the script and is not persisted or shared across sessions.

Comment: There's nothing built-in that does this. All those caching methods use external processes and have to serialize the data, which may not be any faster than reading from a file in the application. Just use a compact, efficient file format like `serialize()` (that's what PHP uses internally for `$_SESSION`).

Comment: A MySQL memory table for a small amount of shared data is quite fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does php provide an API for cross-session data management? No

Does php provide a mechanism for reading and updating data? Yes there's lots of them

While this sounds like a session handler which is shared across multiple users, it's implementation is *very* different. By default (and by necessity) php's sessions are blocking. If the access to this shared dataset was blocking then you would severely limit concurrency.

Given that the access to the data must be non-blocking, how do you mediate concurrent updates to the shared data? A lot depends on the frequency of the updates. But there's also questions about capacity and whether you need to support multiple nodes.

Any one-size-all solution for the functionality is going to be severely hampered in capacity and/or performance. There are lots of products PHP will integrate with to provide a suitable storage substrate, however (leaving aside the logic of the interface for your super-session) it is not in the nature of open source software to package up third party products and hide them behind APIs.